# European or Danish data set that specifies roof types

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am looking for a data set that specifies the roof types (flat/hip/gable) of buildings in Denmark.
A second best result would be the same data for another Northern European country.

I have looked into the [cadastral data of Denmark](https://download.kortforsyningen.dk/) but could not identify datasets that would contain the roof type (they do have a [Minecraft dataset though](https://download.kortforsyningen.dk/content/geodataprodukter?field_korttype_tid_1=3615)).

Would anyone know of such a dataset for Denmark or any other Northern European country?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to have a look at OpenStreetMap (OSM).

There is a supported tag in OSM to specify which type of roof covers a building: the "roof:shape=*" key. Please see [this page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Simple_3D_buildings) for full information about this tag and some interesting links of webmaps/projects about rendering buildings in 3D from OSM information.

A quick [query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/oac) on the OSM database through overpass-turbo shows that there is only 3326 buildings with roof description in Denmark. A drop of water in the ocean, but you can still further check some Danish places or other cities to see if some part might be exploitable for your purpose.

Julien

Comment: Wow, cool. Indeed a very small sample, but interesting nonetheless.